# Build an archive of Phonegap project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova

I created an Phonegap app for iOS devices. It works fine on my connected device, but if I want to archive the app to get an .ipa file I get errors from the compiler.

Do I have to change something in the Build Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

1. Go to the Build Settings, then Linking, then find Other Linker Flags. Then change $(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libCordova.a **----->** $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a
2. Under Build Settings in Architectures, change Build Active Architecture Only to YES.

I'd try both these methods for the Project and Target. Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like that he doesn't find the libCordova.a, but I did not delete anything.

Looks like this now: http://d.pr/i/9Gro

Comment: Did you change Build Active Architecture Only to YES on the Cordova Project & Target instead of on your app Project & Target?

Comment: In CordovaLib Project & Target I switched Build Active Architecture Only to Yes.

In StudiSportOS Project & Target I changed the Other Linker Flags as you said.

Comment: Ok, here are the settings for my architecture for the app http://d.pr/i/4NIm and for cordova http://d.pr/i/Xe63. Copy these settings and let me know if it works. And remember to clean from the product tab first!

Comment: What did you change? Did copying my settings help at all?

Comment: I just created a new project and changed the TARGET_BUILD_DIR to BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR and it worked.

Comment: @square Haven't done it again since when. But I wrote how it worked for me.

Comment: @torhoehn can you give me step so i can check where is the problem